# Why is this Relation R (graph) not transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let the arrow graph of R be the following:

[image]

If we get the ordered pairs we have that

R = { (a,a), (a,b), (a,c), (b,b), (b,a), (b,c), (c,a), (c,b), (d,d) }

If we analyze this:

*Reflexive - NOT TRUE. Because there aren't x = x for every ordered pair in the set

*Symmetric - TRUE. Because for every (x,y) there is a (y,x)

Question: Transitive?

My professor said that this was not transitive. I am wondering why.

With the pairs we can see that for every (x,y) -> (y,z) there is indeed a (x,z) pair.

Could you please tell me why this is NOT TRANSITIVE?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R$ does not contain $(c,c)$ and this while $cRa\wedge aRc$. This contradicts that $R$ is transitive.

---

In general a relation $S$ is transitive if $uSv\wedge vSw$ implies that $uSw$.

Comment: I thought that that was for symmetry? I don't think that being transitive depends on symmetry? Am I wrong?

Comment: $S$ is symmetric if $uSv$ implies $vSu$. That is a different property.

Comment: Look what I am saying in general about a transitive relation $S$ and fill in $u=c$, $v=a$ and $w=c$. Only focus on transitivity here, and not on things like reflexivity or symmetry. They are only confusing you.

Comment: ooooooooooooooh! I kinda get it now, correct me if I am wrong. So for every single pair, you shall check if the condition exists. A valid transitivity check would be (a,b) -> (b,a) therefore (a,a). If we do this with (c,a) -> (a,c) we get to the conclusion that it is not transitive since (c,c) does not exist, am I right?

Comment: yyyyyyyyyyyyes!!!

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> With the pairs we can see that for every $(x,y)\to (y,z)$ there is indeed a $(x,z)$ pair.

Are you sure? What about $c,a,b$?

Comment: regarding symmetry or reflexivity?

Comment: @JJ-Dallara: You asked about _transitivity_, and that's what all the answers are talking about.

Comment: I know. It is definitely symmetric but I have no idea why would it not be transitive still

Comment: @JJ-dallara A relation is symmetric if for any selection of $x,y,z$ such that $xRy$ and $yRz$ is true, $xRz$ is also true. In your case, $cRa$ and $aRb$ is true. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at $(c,a)$ and $(a,c)$.

Comment: so therefore is not symmetric?

Comment: @JJ-Dallara: The relation _is_ symmetric. Why wouldn't it be symmetric?

Comment: This is a hint to show it's not transitive.  In the definition of transitivity: for all $x,y,z$, $xRy$ and $yRz$ implies $xRz$, the elements $x,y,z$ need not be distinct.

Comment: sorry im kinda lost. As I said, for every (x,y) there is an (y,x). I don't understand your hint. Could you explain further? Thank you! :)

Comment: @JJD In the definition of transitivity (see comment above), let $x=c, y=a, z=c$.  Does transitivity hold?

Comment: You are so right!!!! THANK YOU!!!!